# I am confused as to how to get the hat symbol and my subscript directly above and below eachother as in the image

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

[image]

Whenever I try to do this i get them off to the side. when i am working with simple characters such as just an x and a y as my superscripts and subscripts it works but not when i am using complex ones

Comment: Post minimal code to reproduce.

Comment: @Paige Please, next time provide an MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you use `\hat{e_x}` instead of `\hat {e}_x`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    $\mathbf{r} = 2\hat{e}_x + \hat{e}_y$

\end{document}
```

[image]